# Suppose $y^{-1}xy=x^2$, prove by induction that $y^{-n}xy^n=x^{2^n}$ for $n \ge 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction

I'm currently doing my first course of abstract algebra and I'm having difficulty understanding how to prove the $n+1$ case for an exercise.
The problem is:
Let $x, y \in G$ be elements of a group $G$. Suppose
$$y^{-1}xy=x^{2}.$$
Prove by induction that the following holds for all $n \ge 0$.
$$y^{-n}xy^{n}=x^{2^{n}}.$$
I did the base case:
$$y^{-0}xy^{0}=x=x^{1}=x^{2^{0}}.$$
For the induction step, I would like to have some hints:
$$y^{-(n+1)}xy^{n+1}=y^{-n}y^{-1}xyy^{n}=y^{-n}x^{2}y^{n}= \text{Stuck here.}$$
I assumed that I could rearrange the
$$y^{n+1}=y^{1+n} \implies y^ny=yy^n$$
but I have no information on if the group is abelian. So can I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: An element always commutes with itself, so yes, you can rearrange your $y's$ with each other, just not other things

Comment: Hint: $y^{-n} x^2 y^n = y^{-n} xx y^n = y^{-n} x y^n y^{-n} x y^n$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I understand that $$x^2=xx$$ but don't see how you can suddenly introduce $$xy^ny^{-n}x$$

Comment: Well, $y^ny^{-n}$ is the identity $e$, so I can just introduce that term whenever and wherever I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a more abstract point of view.

Define $f:G \rightarrow G$ such that $f(z) = y^{-1}zy$. Then one can verify that $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to itself, i.e. $f(zw) = f(z)f(w)$ for any $z, w\in G$.

Now we know that $f(x) = x^2$, and we want to prove that $f^{(n)}(x) = x^{2^n}$. Here $f^{(n)}$ means applying $f$ $n$ times.

It is clear for $n = 0$. Suppose it's true for $n$. We then have: $$f^{(n + 1)}(x) = f(f^{(n)}(x)) = f(x^{2^n}) = f(x)^{2^n} = \left(x^2\right)^{2^n} = x^{2^{n + 1}}$$ as desired.